# get the direction of a street in android

Tags: android, android-maps

Suppose I have a street name, is there a way to find whether that street is an East-West Street or a North-South Street???

So say for eg I have a street named John Street, how can I find whether it heads in East-West direction or South-North direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, it's probably dangerous to assume that roads always run N-S or E-W. That's not taking into account situations where either geographical features, or the slow disorganised build-up of an urban area, has mandated roads that curve, or run NW-SE for example.

However, provided you have [a means to extract relatively accurate GPS co-ordinates from a street address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), you could *try* getting the co-ordinates for `1 John St` and `21 John St` and using the difference to calculate which direction the road goes at that point.

Short of finding a nice simple Android API call called something like `GetStreetDirection()`, the differential GPS co-ordinates would be the first method I'd be looking at.